# Android music app that properly reads/writes MP3 ID3 POPM tags

Tags: music, id3, android-app

I'm hoping to find an Android app that can properly read and write MP3 ID3 tags for ratings (usually a popularity meter, called POPM in the tag). It's Matroska T=30 in the ID3v2.3 and IDv2.4 tags, and it's an 8-bit value in code (1-255), so it wouldn't be difficult to program the thresholds into a program for each full and half-star rating, e.g.:

| ID3 value | Stars |
| --- | --- |
| <23 | 0 |
| <46 | 0.5 |
| <69 | 1 |
| <92 | 1.5 |
| <115 | 2 |
| <138 | 2.5 |
| <161 | 3 |
| <184 | 3.5 |
| <207 | 4 |
| <230 | 4.5 |
| <253 | 5 |

Anyway, I have yet to find a program that supports multiple genre tags AND full star ratings on Android.

Poweramp is close with some third-party help. Poweramp does have a rating system, but it's not POPM in the MP3 ID3v2.3/ID3v2.4 tags and it doesn't support half-star ratings.

There is a third-party program that can synchronize in either direction though called Music Playlist Manager by flyingdutchman. I linked a Tasker script to automate that process on this forum post https://forum.powerampapp.com/topic/22162-poweramp-finally-needs-a-half-star-rating-system/
However, this sync process still loses your half-star ratings if you use those.

Any suggestions on other programs?